# How to add horizontal line at front of the line bullet in live data amcharts

Tags: amcharts4

i'm working on amchart live data you can check here https://www.amcharts.com/demos/live-data/. So i want to add horizonal line at front of the line bullet like you can check here https://iqoption.com/en/ in this site when you signup and click on trade there will be chart show. at front of the line bullet there is horizontal line  i want like this. So let me know is it possible ??

Answer (score 0):

Amchart is a quite popular charting library, and after a few minutes of searches, it is a quite easy task to do.

Based on the live-data demo provided by amchart your have to add some line to that code.

To start add an axisrange line to the chart.

```
// goal guides
var axisRange = valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
axisRange.value = 4;
axisRange.grid.strokeOpacity = 1;
axisRange.label.text = "Goal"; // This text will be displayed on the right side of chart.
axisRange.label.align = "right";
axisRange.label.verticalCenter = "bottom";
axisRange.label.fillOpacity = 0.8;
```

After this block you will see the vertical line on the chart but this will not move along the chart

In order to start to move the line you have to modify the startInterval() function

From the function your have access to the previously declared axisrange variable
so after getting the next value you have to assign this value to the axisrange position and label this way

```
function startInterval() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        visits =
            visits + Math.random();
        var lastdataItem = series.dataItems.getIndex(series.dataItems.length - 1);
        chart.addData(
            { date: new Date(lastdataItem.dateX.getTime() + 1000), value: visits },
            1
        );
       // Add this two line to the startinterval function or where you 
          calculate the next value
      axisRange.value=visits;
      axisRange.label.text=visits;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not the answer of my question.

Comment: I want to add the stick horizontal line on bullet which is showing at front  of the line bullet

Comment: I made a misunderstand. Edited my answear hope this one helps

Comment: Sorry bro, it's not working as i want. If you want I can share my code